# ¿Cómo puedo mostrar el texto de un JLabel temporalmente luego de realizar una acción (presionar boton)? (Java)

Tags: java, java-swing, interfaz-gráfica

Recurro a la comunidad para intentar implementar una acción en mi programa.
Es un programa básico con interfaz gráfica, basicamente va de pulsar un botón, al pulsarlo, arroja un mensaje `etiqueta1.setText("Ha pulsado el boton");` mediante un `ActionListener()` aplicado al botón. La idea era que ese mensaje solo permaneciera N segundos en pantalla y luego desapareciera.

He investigado un poco y descubrí dos clases que podrían permitirme hacerlo: `Timer()` y `TimerTask()` pero no encontré una implementación en un programa con interfaz.

Comparto el código. (El método `main` está en otra clase :)

```
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class Vista extends JFrame{
JPanel panel;
JLabel etiqueta1;
JButton boton1;

public Vista(){
    this.setSize(300, 300);
    this.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    this.setResizable(false);
    this.setTitle("Pulsame");
    
    iniciarComponentes();
    this.setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
}

private void iniciarComponentes(){
    paneles();
    etiquetas();
    botones();
}

private void paneles(){
    panel = new JPanel();
    panel.setLayout(null);
    this.getContentPane().add(panel);
}

private void etiquetas(){
    etiqueta1 = new JLabel("");
    etiqueta1.setBounds(90, 50, 300, 30);
    
    panel.add(etiqueta1);
}

private void botones(){
    boton1 = new JButton("Púlsame");
    boton1.setBounds(100, 150, 100, 30);
    
    panel.add(boton1);
    oyenteAccion();
}

private void oyenteAccion(){
    ActionListener accionBoton = new ActionListener() {
        
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) {
            //la idea es que este mensaje sea temporal en pantalla
            etiqueta1.setText("Ha pulsado el botón");
        }
    };
    boton1.addActionListener(accionBoton);
}
```

Comparto imagenes del programa:

[image: Antes de pulsar el boton]

[image: Muestra a través de un JLabel el texto "Ha pulsado el boton"]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Podes crear un temporizador con la clase `Timer` donde se agrega el evento del botón, pero fuera del ActionListener. Por ejemplo:

```
import javax.swing.Timer; // No confundir con java.util.Timer.

private void oyenteAccion(){
    //la idea es que este mensaje sea temporal en pantalla
    Timer timer = new Timer(3000, e -> { // 3 segundos
        etiqueta1.setText("");
    });

    timer.setRepeats(false);

    boton1.addActionListener(e -> {
        String newText = "Ha pulsado el botón";

        etiqueta1.setText(newText);
        
        timer.restart();
    });
}
```

La razón de agregarlo fuera del ActionListener es para reutilizar el mismo temporizador sin tener que crear uno cada vez que se presiona el botón.

La clase Timer contiene métodos útiles para iniciar, reiniciar y parar el temporizador, ademas de contener métodos para comprobar si esta en ejecución.

La documentación se encuentra aquí: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/Timer.html

Comment: Hola @JFrame, deberías agregar **timer.stop();** después de **etiqueta1.setText("");**, a fin de que no quede el hilo en marcha.

Comment: @MarcePuente Tienes razón, no me di cuenta de eso. Aun así sería mejor timer.setRepeats(false) que hace que el temporizador se detenga después de enviar su primer evento. Esto para no luchar con "The local variable timer may not have been initialized" y no tener que agregar mas código para tratar de detenerlo.

Comment: acabo de aprender algo que no sabía, maestro, mi más sincero agradecimiento, usted es uno de los colaboradores de los que siempre leo las respuestas, para "robarle" un poquito de conocimiento.